# Delete all characters/words that doesn't match a pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, vi

I have a text, without lines, and i want to delete all the characters that doesn't match a pattern:

The pattern would be from the word parameter until it finds `}}`. For example if i have this entry:

```
KHJLMNNamespaceparameter:{{"Hello i am here"}}NamespaceHSKFSAFSLLLJparameter:{{H}}...
```

I would like to delete everything and leave this in the file: `parameter:{{"Hello i am here"}} parameter:{{H}}`.

All i found out there is to delete a line that doesn't contain a pattern, but I am not able to find anything related with a huge file without /n(end of lines). It would be possible to do that using either sed, awk or Vi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="}}"} sub(/.*parameter/,"parameter")' file
parameter:{{"Hello i am here"}}parameter:{{H}}
```

Note that this is gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS.

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is an option, you can do this:

```
perl -ne "my @wo = ($_ =~ /parameter:\{\{.*?\}\}/g); print join(' ',@wo);" your_text_file
```

In perl, the modifier `*?` is a non-greedy quantifier, such that it stops at the first encountered `}}`.

I think a perl expert can do this in one instruction, without a temporary array ...

**EDIT**: this command only outputs the wanted text on stdout. To change the file itself, use the switch `-i` when calling perl:

```
perl -i.bak -ne "my @wo = ($_ =~ /parameter:\{\{.*?\}\}/g); print join(' ',@wo);" your_text_file
```

A backup file is created with the extension .bak appended at the end, and the result is written in a file with the same name as the input filename. Note that you can get no backup file with the swtich `-i` alone, but some platforms don't allowed this. See [doc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more information.

Comment: I just tested but it doesn't work... thanks anyways!

Comment: Works for me, output is the same as what you want. Could you please be more precise on the error/failure? Which version of perl are you using? Mine is 5.20.1

Comment: It just doesn't print any output. All I do is your command in the terminal on macOSX, perl -ne "my @wo = ($_ =~ /parameter:\{\{.*?\}\}/g); print join(' ',@wo);" output.txt ,but it doesn't print anything...

My version of perl is 5.16.0

Comment: @iOSAddicted just saying "it doesn't work" is a long, LONG way from useful feedback and gives us zero chance to try to help you figure out what is wrong. If you want help, put a tiny bit of effort into helping us to help you.

Comment: Using the -i.bak creates and output.txt.bak with the same exact output as the input of my output.txt file. Sorry for not giving more details before...

Comment: I am sorry, i must be doing something wrong because i get the same output... The first AWK answer(3rd answer) work for me

Comment: @iOSAddicted If you call perl with the additional switch `-w`, do you get a message?Normally it shouldn't...

Comment: @iOSAddicted Ok, so bad ... I don't understand why (tested under [a regexp online tester](https://regex101.com/) with capturing parentheses around the regexp, and it's ok). And the answer of EdMorton fits your request, so use it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `grep` with `-P` (PCRE) regex:

```
grep -oP '.*?\Kparameter:\{\{.*?\}\}' file
parameter:{{"Hello i am here"}}
parameter:{{H}}
```